# Power required to reach X velocity in X time with drag

Tags: drag, power

I wrote a program that adds force to a car like so:

- *Engine Force = Power / Velocity​*
- *Drag Force = -Velocity²​*
- *Net Force = Engine Force - Drag Force = Power / Velocity - Velocity²​*

I'd like to determine power based on how fast I want a car of a given mass to reach a given speed, for example, 0 to 20 m/s in 10 seconds for a 1000 kg car. Here is the equation I came up with to calculate the power needed without any drag:

- *Power = (1000 ⋅ 2) ⋅ (100 / 10) = 20,000 W to go from 0 to 20 m/s in 10 seconds for a 1000 kg car*
- *Using it to solve the example:*
- *Mass = 1000 kg​*
- *Time = 10 s​*
- *Average Acceleration = 20 / 10 = 2 m/s*​
- *Displacement = 0.5 ⋅ 2 ⋅ 10² = 100 m​*
- *Power = (1000 ⋅ 2) ⋅ (100 / 10) = 20,000 W​ to go from 0 to 20 m/s in 10 seconds for a 1000 kg car*
  ​

I'm not sure if that equation is sound but it calculates the power needed in a vacuum perfectly. The problems start when I try to account for drag:

- *Net Force = Power / Velocity - Speed²​*
- *Net Force + Speed² = Power / Velocity*
- *Power = (Net Force + Velocity²) ⋅ Velocity*
- *Power = [(Mass ⋅ Average Acceleration) + (Displacement / Time)²] ⋅ (Displacement / Time) = 21,000 W​*

This is incorrect. When I run my program with the calculated power, it takes the car ~11.5 s to reach 20 m/s, not 10 s. By trial and error, I determined that the correct value is ~23,500 W.

I've tried all day to find the correct equation with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need some empirical coefficient to compute drag force from velocity (also to match dimensions)

Comment: @Icv I am totally out of my element here so bear with me, but how should I go about this?

Comment: This coefficient (with unit of force over velocity squared), is a property of the object. An areodynamic, sport car will have a smaller coefficient than a truck.

Comment: Actually what is normally called drug coefficient is a dimensionless quantity, but my point still stands. You need a dimensional coefficient to obtain a force from velocity squared

Comment: I would have guessed that the behaviour you have, that you need more power to reach the same speed in the same time, was correct, though the size of the difference could be wrong. You could try doing a spreadsheet with different inputs, and try to see how that matches things in the real world. You might be able to look up terminal velocity for some things. That is the speed where drag matches the gravity force and could give you a handle on same numbers to put in.

Comment: @Icv I simplified my drag equation to 1 * v² in my program

Comment: @Belaidex I understand. But that 1 actually stands for 1( Kg m / sec^2)/(m/sec)^2. If you want your numbers to have anything to do with typical cars take a look at 'drag coefficient' and typical automobile drag coefficient. You need to know the area of impact of the car, and density of air.

Comment: To be concrete: that "1" would change if you measure speed in km/h or Miles per hour.

Comment: @Icv I see. I'm trying to first figure out how to calculate power based on the stated inputs before I move on to making my drag equation accurate.